# Make Page available only thorough redirect and not by direct url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some webpages which I want to appear only through internal redirects, such that even if someone just types in the url they wouldn't go through. To see them you would need to go through the page that redirects to the 'secure page'.

Comment: set session > redirect >check session

Comment: You could generate a random token on the first page, store it in database and in session, and on the second page compare these values and allow the user to see the page

Comment: And what are your requirements for page reload/refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTTP_REFERER from the $_SERVER super global.

At the top of the restricted page:

```
<?php
// if the referrer is not the page you want the traffic coming from (http://yourdomain.com/allowed_from_page.php), redirect back to that page.
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'http://yourdomain.com/allowed_from_page.php')
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/allowed_from_page.php');
```

Comment: Thanx.   user574632 's idea of sessions was also nice.

Comment: I hope you're using this just for convenience and not for security as this is easily faked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the page that will redirect to the specified page:

```
<form action="./redirectedpage.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="protection" value="yes"/>
<input type="submit" value="Go to Protected Page">
</form>
```

Add this on the page that can not be acessed directly:

```
<?php
$unlock = $_POST['protection'];
if ($unlock == 'yes'){
?>

**:: YOUR CODE GOES HERE ::**


<?php

} // END OF THE LOCK CODE
else {
// REDIRECTS USER TO HOME IF HE IS NOT UNLOCKED or IF HE ACCESS THE PAGE DIRECTLY
header('Location: http://myhomepage.com/index.php');
}

?>
```

Keep in mind that this is a simple example, that do not uses sessions and similars. If you need something more **"SECURE"** you will need to use, SCAPE($unlock = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['protection']);), and other security stuffs. If you didn't understood please let me know it.

Comment: This will only work if it's a form that redirects to the target page, not if it's a simple link.

Comment: It's pretty easy to use a common link to submit a form, anyway @c-griffin's answer is way better, simple and easier then mine, also I'm with adam0101 if he wants security he will need other stuffs and code lines.By the way it looks like he needs a simple page protect, not a secure one.